# selenium (python): Errno 101 Connection Refused on screenshot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have just today encountered a new error in a previously working piece of code. Here is the code in question, using selenium webdriver in python:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.reference.com"))
data = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()`

and the error I receive:

```
File "screenshotMachine.py", line 270, in receiveJob
doCaptureTearsheet(jobBody)
    File "screenshotMachine.py", line 191, in doCaptureTearsheet
url = captureTearsheet(campaignID, h, w, m, tearsheetNumber, month, source)
    File "/home/trevor/storage/PaperG/tearsheet-service/worker/etearsheet.py", line 82, in captureTearsheet
data = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 725, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 347, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 377, in _request
self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
    error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Like I said, this code was working fine until this morning. A git blame shows that this code has not changed in over a month. I'm at a loss of what to do here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems it was an error on my part. I was calling `driver.quit()` before taking the screenshot. I think this error message could have been more clear, but oh well.

Going to leave the answer here just in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Hello, Trevor. I can not find driver.quit() in your code. where did you write quit func?